# How to rewrite a sub query in a select clause as a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, common-table-expression

I need to rewrite an SQL query so that it doesn't contain any sub-queries due to the requirements of a third party program that will be executing it. However I know only a little SQL and haven't been able to find anything that helps me so far.

An example of the sub-query I would need to rewrite is:

```
SELECT
DateAdd(millisecond
, ISnull((select RawOffset 
from tbl_lms_TimeZoneData 
where TimeZone_FK = (act.TimeZoneFK) ),0) 

, DateAdd(millisecond
, ISnull((select Offset 
from tbl_lms_ConvertTimeZoneData 
where TimeZone_FK = (act.TimeZoneFK) 
and act.StartDt between StartDate and EndDate),0) , act.StartDt)) 
as N'Activity Start Date'

FROM
etc...
```

act is defined in the FROM clause.

The query works as is but any attempt from me to substitute the sub-query with a CTE breaks it.

Is it possible to replace the sub-query in this case?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Zane The maple kind. [Source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGeKSiCQkPw)

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server so it should be a relational DBMS.

Comment: SQL Server was the answer I was looking for thanks.

Comment: @Zane We need to test to make sure it's relational

Comment: It looks possible to me, but it's hard to tell without your whole query.  Can  you please post ALL of your original query, and also what you tried?  I can tell you what your mistake is, but only if I can see your attempt.

Comment: seems like you should be able to do this using LEFT JOINs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you even need CTE here? Looks like you can simply use outer join.

```
SELECT DateAdd(millisecond, 
               ISnull(tzd.RawOffset,0),
                      DateAdd(millisecond,
                              ISnull(ctzd.Offset,0),
                              Act.StartDt)) as N'Activity Start Date'
    FROM Act
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_lms_TimeZoneData tzd
            ON tzd.TimeZone_FK = act.TimeZoneFK
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_lms_ConvertTimeZoneData ctzd
            ON ctzd.TimeZone_FK = act.TimeZoneFK
            AND act.StartDt between ctzd.StartDate and ctzd.EndDate
```

Not sure what a condition on Act is doing in the subquery from tbl_lms_ConvertTimeZoneData but I kept it.

UPD: I guess, Start and End actually belong to tbl_lms_ConvertTimeZoneData. Modified the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you end up having to use CTEs, you should be able to get way with doing them like this:

```
WITH cte_TimeZoneData AS (
    SELECT  RawOffset, TimeZone_FK
    FROM    dbo.tbl_lms_TimeZoneData ),
cte_ConvertTimeZoneData AS (
    SELECT  Offset, TimeZone_FK, StartDate, EndDate
    FROM    dbo.tbl_lms_ConvertTimeZoneData )
SELECT  [Activity Start Date] = DATEADD( MILLISECOND,
            ISNULL( tzd.RawOffset, 0 ), DATEADD( MILLISECOND,
            ISNULL( ctzd.Offset, 0 ), act.StartDt ) )
FROM    dbo.Act act
LEFT JOIN cte_TimeZoneData tzd
    ON  act.TimeZoneFK = tzd.TimeZone_FK
LEFT JOIN cte_ConvertTimeZoneData ctzd
    ON  act.TimeZoneFK = ctzd.TimeZone_FK
    AND act.StartDt >= ctzd.StartDate
    AND act.StartDt < ctzd.EndDate;
```